# Attaching 2 jQuery "click events" only work once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

Once I click on the image tag it opens the sidebar and it rotates the arrow to the right and when i click again it closes the sidebar and rotate back the arrow but the function doesn't work anymore after that and this is my problem here....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("img").on("click", function() {
    $('#right-panel').addClass("visible");
    $('#leftarrow').rotate({
      animateTo: 180
    });
    $("img").on("click", function() {
      $('#right-panel').removeClass("visible");
      $('#leftarrow').rotate({
        animateTo: 0
      });
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe ui light", san-serif;
  color: orange;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: orange !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
/* right panel */

#right-panel {
  position: absolute;
  right: -120px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: right 0.3s linear;
}
#right-panel.visible {
  right: 0px;
  transition: right 0.3s linear;
}
/* absence box */

.absence-box {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 64;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 1s;
}
.absence-box:active {
  background-color: #000;
}
.absence-box:hover {
  background-color: #abaaaa;
}
.absence-box p:hover {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
}
.absence-box p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
  transition: color 1s;
}
/* presence box */

.presence-box {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 196);
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 64;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.presence-box p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
}
/* Working box */

.working-box {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(69, 105, 166);
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 64;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.working-box p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
h6 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.absence-box h6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  right: -65px;
}
.presence-box h6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  right: -65px;
}
.working-box h6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  right: -65px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
img.leftarrow {
  background-image: src('imgs/leftarrow.png');
}
img.rightarrow {
  background-image: url("imgs/rightarrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<!-- Right panel -->
<div id="right-panel">

  <img src="imgs/leftarrow.png" id="leftarrow" />

  <!-- absence box -->
  <div class="absence-box">
    <p>A</p>
    <h6>Absence</h6>
  </div>

  <!-- presence box -->
  <div class="presence-box">
    <p>P</p>
    <h6>Presence</h6>
  </div>


  <!-- Working box -->
  <div class="working-box">
    <p>W</p>
    <h6>Working on Order</h6>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: because they both fire...

Comment: Set your code in one handler and make decision on visible class availabiliy `if ($('#right-panel').hasClass('visible')) { ... }`

Comment: When I fixed the snippet, the indentation also shows that the first click of the image assigns the second handler

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out here I am testing each suggestion now. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just use the **toggleClass** function to add / remove the class "visible":

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").on("click", function(){
            $('#right-panel').toggleClass("visible");
        });
    });
```

For rotating the image I would recommend you to use **CSS3**:

```
.visible img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);

  -webkit-transition: transform 300ms ease;
  transition: transform 300ms ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Entertain for your CSS tip I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You likely meant

```js
$("img").on("click", function() {
  $('#right-panel').toggleClass("visible");
  $('#leftarrow').rotate({
    animateTo: $('#right-panel').hasClass("visible") ? 180 : 0
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe ui light", san-serif;
  color: orange;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: orange !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.main {
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
/* right panel */

#right-panel {
  position: absolute;
  right: -120px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: right 0.3s linear;
}
#right-panel.visible {
  right: 0px;
  transition: right 0.3s linear;
}
/* absence box */

.absence-box {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 64;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 1s;
}
.absence-box:active {
  background-color: #000;
}
.absence-box:hover {
  background-color: #abaaaa;
}
.absence-box p:hover {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
}
.absence-box p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
  transition: color 1s;
}
/* presence box */

.presence-box {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 196);
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 64;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.presence-box p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
}
/* Working box */

.working-box {
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: rgb(69, 105, 166);
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 64;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.working-box p {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: segoe ui light;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}
h6 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.absence-box h6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  right: -65px;
}
.presence-box h6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  right: -65px;
}
.working-box h6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  right: -65px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
img.leftarrow {
  background-image: src('imgs/leftarrow.png');
}
img.rightarrow {
  background-image: url("imgs/rightarrow.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<!-- Right panel -->
<div id="right-panel">

  <img src="http://www.valencia.org/images/leftArrow.png" id="leftarrow" height="32"/>

  <!-- absence box -->
  <div class="absence-box">
    <p>A</p>
    <h6>Absence</h6>
  </div>

  <!-- presence box -->
  <div class="presence-box">
    <p>P</p>
    <h6>Presence</h6>
  </div>


  <!-- Working box -->
  <div class="working-box">
    <p>W</p>
    <h6>Working on Order</h6>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("img").on("click", function(){

            var
            rotate = 0;

            if (!$('#right-panel').hasClass("visible")) {

                rotate = 180;
            }

            $('#leftarrow').rotate({animateTo: rotate});
            $('#right-panel').toggleClass("visible");
        });
    });
```